# Multiple submit button gets null in controller ActionResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I went through all related problems here in stackoverflow but I still can't get my code to work. I Made my Code simple for this. When I click the button I still can go to ActionResult Create in my controller but string btn still returns null.
Then
I tried this code to my other project created a TestController with the same code below and It now works.
I tried to compare and adding the references missing in my project but it didn't solved it.

Thanks in advance

```
> @{
>     ViewBag.Title = "Create"; } <h2>Create</h2>
> 
>     @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
>     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
>     <button name="btn" value="SELL" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sell</button>
>     <button name="btn" value="BUY" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Buy</button> }
> 
> <div>@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") </div>
> 


  //Controller        
>[HttpGet]
>public ActionResult Create()
>{
>   return View();
>}
>         
>[HttpPost]
>[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
>public ActionResult Create(string btn)
>{
>    if (btn == "BUY")
>    {
>       trade.Type = 'B';
>    }
>    else if (btn == "SELL")
>    {
>       trade.Type = 'S';
>    }       
>    return View();
>}
```

Comment: You need a `<form>`, it is the content of the `<form>` which are submitted to the controller. [this article might help](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/submitting-a-form-to-different-action-methods-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Do you mean @using (Html.BeginForm()), I already have it, and another <form> where the buttons are located

Comment: Yes, `Html.BeginForm` is an MVC helper which will generate an HTML `<form>` tag... It's up to your weather to use `Html.BeginForm`  to generate your form or not, but when you click on submit button, you are submitting the content of a `<form>`

Comment: I attached an image above, Is There a problem if I use two forms?

Comment: If you are adding another `<form>`, it will submit for that specified form. You could use a div and add the class `form-group` to it, and that should work.

Comment: @jcoflorin: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)... it would help you to improve the question and hopefully you will get better advice. The screen shot that you have included contains only one form...

Comment: I edited my Question above hope it's clearer now.

Comment: OKay I dugged deep and found that if I remove this "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" from my bundleconfig it now works. I dont anything about jquery but can anyone help me out on this. Why does it affect my submit buttons?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini The First link helps, since I can't do anything about the jQuery. I just have to create another url for the action result for each button. Thanks man